# Running Abaqus/Explicit with GPU assistance

Tags: abaqus

I wih to run **ABAQUS/Explicit with GPU assistance**... 
Officially SIMULIA has not provided GPU capabilities to ABAQUS/Explicit (only to ABAQUS/Standard). However, in the link below it is described an approach to run Abaqus/explicit with GPU assistance using OpenACC.
https://youtu.be/lqD2gCql_nk

1. ***Does anyone knows how to do it?*** ... or
2. ***Does anyone knows of
   what documentation/video I can check to be able to do it?***

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: @talonmies, Could you provide a comment for the down vote please?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from the webpages that ABAQUS/Explicit is a commercial solver. That means that you run it using the GUI and the code is not available to you.

If that is correct, then OpenACC does not help you. You can use OpenACC or OpenMP or MPI etc. if you have the code available and you can modify it to use parallelism.